# Firebase can't find WebSocket implementation when bundled using Webpack

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack

The application was running fine until I threw Webpack on the mix. This is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  target: 'node',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  node: {
    __dirname: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

I can see that one of the modules (I'm pretty sure is *faye-websocket*) in the generated Webpack bundle exports a `WebSocket` object:

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
    var WebSocket = function(request, socket, body, protocols, options) {
      //... code
    };
    //... more code
    module.exports        = WebSocket;
});
```

However, it seems like Firebase is not importing from *faye-websocket* but is looking for the existence of a couple of globals objects instead. In my case, both objects are undefined:

```
if (typeof MozWebSocket !== 'undefined') {
    WebSocketImpl = MozWebSocket;
} else if (typeof WebSocket !== 'undefined') {
    WebSocketImpl = WebSocket;
}
```

Later on on the execution both`BrowserPollConnection` and `WebSocketConnection` return `false` on their `isAvailable()` call, which results on an error being thrown:

```
'No transports available'
```

Is there a way I can guarantee that an implementation of WebSocket is available for Firebase at runtime?

EDIT: Add source code of firebase-crud module

Firebase operations are wrapped in this simple module. The exception is thrown when the `read` function is called, although I'm pretty sure the error would happen on other functions as well.

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
require('firebase/database');


const init = function ({
    apiKey,
    projectId
} = {}) {
    if (!apiKey && !projectId) {
        throw new Error('You need to provide an apiKey and a projectId to initialize Firebase Crud');
    }

    if (!this.database) {
        const config = {
            apiKey,
            authDomain: `${projectId}.firebaseapp.com`,
            databaseURL: `https://${projectId}.firebaseio.com`,
        };

        this.database = firebase.initializeApp(config).database();
    }

    const create = (path, data) => (
        this.database
        .ref(path)
        .set(data)
        .catch(err => console.log(`Error while creating object ${err}`))
    );

    const read = (path) => (
        this.database
        .ref(path)
        .once('value')
        .then((dataSnapshot) => dataSnapshot.val())
        .catch(err => console.log(`Error while reading object ${err}`))
    );

    const update = (path, data) => (
        read(path).then(obj => create(path, Object.assign(obj || {}, data)))
    );

    const _delete = (path) => Promise.reject('Not implemented');

    return {
        create,
        read,
        update,
        delete: _delete
    }
}

module.exports = init;
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WebPack, but perhaps you need target: 'browser' instead of target: 'node' ?

Comment: I'm actually creating a Node app, so the target is appropriated :-)

Comment: I'd love to see more context here, it'd help figure out what is going on. Is it possible to share the contents of ./src/app.ts?

Comment: Hey, @JoshC.! The project is quite big, it is comprised by a few submodules, one of which is a simple implementation of Firebase crud operations. I'm adding the source code of that module to the question with some extra explanation. Cheers!